# Importing keys to a brand new wallet

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

After I imported keys to the brand new wallet I tried to test that it is imported properly so I ran salvagewallet command to verify my new wallet but got these errors!

```
2014-08-21 12:17:28 WARNING: CWalletDB::Recover skipping key: 
2014-08-21 12:17:28 WARNING: CWalletDB::Recover skipping key: Error reading wallet database: CPubKey/CPrivKey corrupt
```

Could you please help me to understand/solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you verify a wallet ?

I think you should use

"C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -zapwallettxes  -dbcache=3000

it will clean the transactions and give you the edge of faster reload.

Answer (score 0):

`salvagewallet` is a disaster recovery tool, you should never be using it as a "verify" for your wallet. Some of the time `salvagewallet` will actually result in loss of funds rather than doing anything useful. Not running the command will fix your problem.